# How to create a stored procedure for calculating average time in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3000 record. 
If I run `select * from TableName`

output:

```
TestSequence    TestName  ExecutionSequence ExecutionSeconds
1                   xyz             1         1.63
1                   xyz             2         1.56
1                   xyz             3         1.55
1                   xyz             4         1.55
1                   xyz             5         1.66
15                  abc             1         0.84
15                  abc             2         0.84
15                  abc             3         0.84
15                  abc             4         0.84
15                  abc             5         0.84
16                  ttt             1         1.75
16                  ttt             2         1.45
16                  ttt             3         1.43
16                  ttt             4         1.48
16                  ttt             5         1.50
17                  www             1         5.22
17                  www             2         5.16
17                  www             3         5.22
17                  www             4         5.21
17                  www             5         5.20
18                  ccc             1         3.48
18                  ccc             2         3.47
18                  ccc             3         3.47
18                  ccc             4         3.47
18                  ccc             5         3.49
```

Each test runs 5 times represented by the column ExecutionSequence, so what I want to achieve is to create a stored procedure that drops or leaves out the maximum and minimum ExecutionSeconds for each testName and calculate the average of the remaining 3. I am trying to build this procedure but am getting stuck.

Here is my code:

```
 USE [db1];  
 GO  
 CREATE PROCEDURE tests_CalculateAverageRunTime
 (  

     @TestSenquence varchar(50) = NULL
  )      
AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON

        SELECT  TestName, TestSequence, AVG(ExecutionSeconds) as AverageRunTime
        FROM TableName 
        WHERE (@TestSenquence IS NULL OR TestSequence = @TestSenquence)

        Group By TestName, TestSequence

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify rows with the maximum and minimum values, and then filter them out:

```
SELECT  TestName, TestSequence, AVG(ExecutionSeconds) as AverageRunTime
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TestName, TestSequence ORDER BY ExecutionSeconds) as seqnum_a,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TestName, TestSequence ORDER BY ExecutionSeconds DESC) as seqnum_d
      FROM TableName t
      WHERE (@TestSenquence IS NULL OR TestSequence = @TestSenquence)
     ) t
WHERE seqnum_a > 1 AND seqnum_d > 1
Group By TestName, TestSequence;
```

In the case of ties for the maximum or minimum, only one is removed.  This is consistent with your desire for an average of three values.